# Separate fullname into first and last, and remove 'junk'

Tags: sql, sql-server

Wasn't sure of the best way to word this. So I have a column with names, as below:

```
SalesPerson_Name
----------------
Undefined - 0
Sam Brett-sbrett
Kelly Roberts-kroberts
Michael Paramore-mparamore
Alivia Lawler-alawler
Ryan Hooker-rhooker
Heather Alford-halford
Cassandra Blegen-cblegen
JD Holland-jholland
Vendor Accounts-VENDOR
Other Accounts-OTHER
```

Getting the names separated is easy enough with PARSENAME and REPLACE functions, but where I'm running into a pickle is with getting rid of the 'junk' at the end:

```
SELECT SalesPerson_Key
    ,SalesPerson_Name
    ,CASE 
        WHEN PARSENAME(REPLACE(SalesPerson_Name, ' ', '.'), 2) IS NULL
            THEN PARSENAME(REPLACE(SalesPerson_Name, ' ', '.'), 1)
        ELSE PARSENAME(REPLACE(SalesPerson_Name, ' ', '.'), 2)
        END AS FirstName
    ,CASE 
        WHEN PARSENAME(REPLACE(SalesPerson_Name, ' ', '.'), 2) IS NULL
            THEN NULL
        ELSE PARSENAME(REPLACE(SalesPerson_Name, ' ', '.'), 1)
        END AS LastName
FROM Salesperson
```

RESULTS FOR LASTNAME COLUMN:

```
LastName
--------
0
Brett-sbrett
Roberts-kroberts
Paramore-mparamore
Lawler-alawler
Hooker-rhooker
Alford-halford
Blegen-cblegen
Holland-jholland
Accounts-VENDOR
Accounts-OTHER
```

Specifically, I want to get rid of the text (userid) at the end of the last name. If the names were the same length, I could just use a RIGHT function, but they vary in length. Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select left(PARSENAME(REPLACE(SalesPerson_Name, ' ', '.'), 1), len(SalesPerson_Name)-CHARINDEX('-',SalesPerson_Name)-1)
```

You are getting charindex of - and taking the left string of it.

Comment: This gets very close. The last couple of entries are a little wonky, so I will use this as a template I think. Thank you!

Comment: Could you please accept it as answer if it works for you. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to remove the last word (username) you can use a query like this

```
select
  rtrim(
    substring(
      SalesPerson_Name,
      1,
      charindex('-',SalesPerson_Name,1)-1
    )
  )
from Salesperson
```

The `charindex` function locates the occurrence of the character/s you are looking for.

Comment: RTRIM only removes spaces, as far as I'm aware

Comment: Yes, some of your names have an space between the name, the -, and the username

Answer (score 0):

Consider whether `hyphen` is followed by a `space` or not, and split depending on these two cases

```
with Salesperson( SalesPerson_Name ) as
(
 select 'Undefined - 0'              union all
 select 'Sam Brett-sbrett'           union all
 select 'Kelly Roberts-kroberts'     union all
 select 'Michael Paramore-mparamore' union all
 select 'Alivia Lawler-alawler'   
)
select case when substring(SalesPerson_Name,charindex(' ',SalesPerson_Name)+1,1) = '-' then
         substring(SalesPerson_Name,charindex(' ',SalesPerson_Name)+3,len(SalesPerson_Name))
       else
         substring(SalesPerson_Name,charindex(' ',SalesPerson_Name)+1,len(SalesPerson_Name))
       end as last_name          
  from Salesperson s;

last_name
------------------
0
Brett-sbrett
Roberts-kroberts
Paramore-mparamore
Lawler-alawler
```

Comment: This still retains the ending username on the last name with the hyphen, unfortunately, but thank you for taking a shot at this.